# uiimageview rotate, not rotating in center

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation

I am trying to setup an gauge meter for one of my projects.

I have two images. one is the gauge background, and the second one is the hand.

the hand is an 110px X 110px image where the center of the hand is in the center of the image.

I load the image to an uiimageview.

When i try to do this:

```
imageViewHand.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4*[slider value]);
```

I get a rotation, but the rotation center is not the center of the image.

the uiimageview is 110px X 110px and the mode is center.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

I am loading the hand image directly through the storyboard.

one additional question, if I use 
 imageViewHand.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.25, 0.25);
to change the pin point, is there any way to show that point? just to get the offsets right?

thanks

Comment: So the main reason why is this happening is that the autolayout in the interface builder document settings was turned on. 

Turning it off solved my question. I guess i have to study more stuff related to layouting.

Comment: you should answer you own question and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile to track down what was meant by autolayout and how to turn it off:

http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/